# how to mock a URL connection

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock, jmockit

Hi I have a method that takes an URL as an input and determines if it is reachable. 
Heres the code for that:

```
public static boolean isUrlAccessible(final String urlToValidate) throws WAGNetworkException {
        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection huc = null;
        int responseCode = -1;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlToValidate);
            huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            huc.connect();
            responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
        } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
            throw new WAGNetworkException(WAGConstants.INTERNET_CONNECTION_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new WAGNetworkException(WAGConstants.INVALID_URL_EXCEPTION);
        } finally {
            if (huc != null) {
                huc.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return responseCode == 200;
    }
```

I want to unit test the isUrlAccessible() method using `PowerMockito`. I feel that I will need to use `whenNew()` to mock the creation of `URL` and the when `url.openConnection()` is called, return another mock `HttpURLConnection` object. But I have am not sure how to implement this? Am I on the right track? Can anyone help me in implementing this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I would suggest you take a good hard look at JMockit (jmockit.github.io) and then see if you can turn away from it--I could not and it's been my go to mocking framework ever since.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution. First mock the URL class, then Mock the HttpURLConnection and when url.openconnection() is called, return this mocked HttpURLConnection object and finally set its response code to 200. Heres the code:

```
@Test
    public void function() throws Exception{
        RuleEngineUtil r = new RuleEngineUtil();
        URL u = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        String url = "http://www.sdsgle.com";
        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withArguments(url).thenReturn(u);
        HttpURLConnection huc = PowerMockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        PowerMockito.when(u.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);
        PowerMockito.when(huc.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);
        assertTrue(r.isUrlAccessible(url));

    }
```

Comment: Does this work, it gives me an error at line  ``PowerMockito.when(u.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);``, saying AbstractMethodError.

Comment: does not work for me either... 
I get: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol

Comment: For mocking URL, you should also consider adding @PrepareForTest({URL.class, <YourImplementationClass>}) as per http://vaguehope.com/2012/02/powermock-puzzler/

Comment: For anyone else who gets an AbstractMethodError in the future, I think the solution may be changing your @Test import from org.junit.jupiter.api.Test to org.junit.Test.

Answer (score 5):

You can mock new Url instance with

```
whenNew(URL.class)..
```

Make sure you return a previously created mock object from that whenNew call.

```
URL mockUrl = Mockito.mock(URL.class);
whenNew(URL.class).....thenReturn(mockUrl );
```

Then you can add behavior to your mock as you want.

Comment: we cant mock a final class (URL)

Comment: @doN, Powermockito can mock a final class (URL).

Answer (score 3):

Although this thread has some good suggestion, but if any of you is not interested to use those third-party libraries here is a quick solution.

```
public class MockHttpURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection {
    private int responseCode;
    private URL url;
    private InputStream inputStream;


    public MockHttpURLConnection(URL u){
        super(null);
        this.url=u;
    }
    @Override
    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }


    public void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getURL() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(URL url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public void setInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnect() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean usingProxy() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException {

    }
}
```

And, this how you can set the desired behaviour

```
   MockHttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=new MockHttpURLConnection(new URL("my_fancy_url"));
        InputStream stream=new ByteArrayInputStream(json_response.getBytes());
        httpURLConnection.setInputStream(stream);
        httpURLConnection.setResponseCode(200);
```

**Note:** It just mock 3 methods from `HttpUrlConnection` and if you are using more method you need to make sure those are mock as well.

Answer (score 2):

URL is final class. To mock final class we can use PowerMockito with Junit.
To mock final class we need to annotate Test class with @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) and @PrepareForTest({ URL.class })

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class })
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        URL url = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection huc = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        PowerMockito.when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);
        assertTrue(url.openConnection() instanceof HttpURLConnection);
    }
}
```

But in the line **PowerMockito.when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);** following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:971)
    at java_net_URL$openConnection.call(Unknown Source)
```

In order to get rid of this error we can modify our Test class as shown below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest({ URL.class })
public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        public class UrlWrapper {

            URL url;

            public UrlWrapper(String spec) throws MalformedURLException {
                url = new URL(spec);
            }

            public URLConnection openConnection() throws IOException {
                return url.openConnection();
            }
        }

        UrlWrapper url = Mockito.mock(UrlWrapper.class);
        HttpURLConnection huc = Mockito.mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        PowerMockito.when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);
        assertTrue(url.openConnection() instanceof HttpURLConnection);
    }
}
```

Visit: https://programmingproblemsandsolutions.blogspot.com/2019/04/abstractmethoderror-is-thrown-on.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to mock java.net.URL class through `mockito` library, you need to perform the following steps:

- Create a directory, named 'mockito-extensions' in src/tests/resources directory.
- Create text a text file in the folder, named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and put `mock-maker-inline` text into the file.
- you can mock the class like the following:

**code:**

```
package myproject;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class Test {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        URL url = mock(URL.class);
        HttpURLConnection huc = mock(HttpURLConnection.class);
        when(url.openConnection()).thenReturn(huc);
        assertTrue(url.openConnection() instanceof HttpURLConnection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler with the JMockit mocking API (and even simpler with no mocking):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import mockit.*;

public final class ExampleURLTest {
   public static final class ClassUnderTest {
      public static boolean isUrlAccessible(String urlToValidate) throws IOException {
         HttpURLConnection huc = null;
         int responseCode;

         try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToValidate);
            huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            huc.connect();
            responseCode = huc.getResponseCode();
         }
         finally {
            if (huc != null) {
               huc.disconnect();
            }
         }

         return responseCode == 200;
      }
   }

   // Proper tests, no unnecessary mocking ///////////////////////////////////////

   @Test
   public void checkAccessibleUrl() throws Exception {
      boolean accessible = ClassUnderTest.isUrlAccessible("http://google.com");

      assertTrue(accessible);
   }

   @Test(expected = UnknownHostException.class)
   public void checkInaccessibleUrl() throws Exception {
      ClassUnderTest.isUrlAccessible("http://inaccessible12345.com");
   }

   @Test
   public void checkUrlWhichReturnsUnexpectedResponseCode(
      @Mocked URL anyURL, @Mocked HttpURLConnection mockConn
   ) throws Exception {
      new Expectations() {{ mockConn.getResponseCode(); result = -1; }};

      boolean accessible = ClassUnderTest.isUrlAccessible("http://invalidResource.com");

      assertFalse(accessible);
   }

   // Lame tests with unnecessary mocking ////////////////////////////////////////

   @Test
   public void checkAccessibleUrl_withUnnecessaryMocking(
      @Mocked URL anyURL, @Mocked HttpURLConnection mockConn
   ) throws Exception {
      new Expectations() {{ mockConn.getResponseCode(); result = 200; }};

      boolean accessible = ClassUnderTest.isUrlAccessible("http://google.com");

      assertTrue(accessible);
   }

   @Test(expected = UnknownHostException.class)
   public void checkInaccessibleUrl_withUnnecessaryMocking(
      @Mocked URL anyURL, @Mocked HttpURLConnection mockConn
   ) throws Exception {
      new Expectations() {{ mockConn.connect(); result = new UnknownHostException(); }};

      ClassUnderTest.isUrlAccessible("http://inaccessible12345.com");
   }
}
```

(Verified with JMockit 1.47 on JDKs 8 & 9.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure `Mockito` before it can be used to mock final classes and methods. (Tested with JUnit 5 & `mockito-core-3.6.28`)

## Steps:

- Create a directory named `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions`
- Inside it, create a file named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker`
- Add a single line inside the file, `mock-maker-inline`

Now, you can mock your final class, example:

```
URL url = Mockito.mock(URL.class)
```

> Note: As per this [issue](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/929), PowerMock does not work with JUnit 5.