# PowerMock java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, powermock, powermockito

I created a mock `HttpsURLConnection` based on an [StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334710/939250):

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

...

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class DialogTest {
    public void mockHttpsUrlConnectionExample() throws Exception
    {
        URL mockUrl = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection mockUrlConnection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpsURLConnection.class);
        PowerMockito.when(mockUrl.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockUrlConnection);
        PowerMockito.when(mockUrlConnection.getResponseCode()).thenReturn(200);

        // Create and call my objects ...

    }
}
```

However, when I use it, I'm seeing a cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
```

The problem lies in this code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

...

private Boolean sendRequest(String endpoint, JSONObject requestData, Boolean throwOnAuthException) throws JSONException, IOException {
    this.responseData = null;

    try {
        String serviceURI = getServiceURI();
        String dialogUri = String.format("%s%s", serviceURI, endpoint);
        URL url = new URL(dialogUri);

        // Exception source is this cast
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

However, when I look at the source code, I see that `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl` implements `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

Any suggestions on how to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The issue a conflict between the regular class loader and PowerMock's**

The drawback to PowerMock is the use of a custom class loader.  This class loader can modify type signatures in a way that is incompatible with the default class loader.

In certain circumstances, instantiation by reflection will cause the default class loader to be used to load a type.  That class loader will not know that a type has already be loaded by PowerMock, because of the use of different signatures.  The result can be casting errors for
 objects that should implement the cast type.

**To avoid this problem, first stop PowerMock from loading `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`**

To prevent the cast exception, use ensure javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection is only loaded by one class loader.  Since I cannot stop the regular class loader from being used, the best approach is to stop the PowerMock loader from acting using the `@PowerMockIgnore` annotation.  E.g.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*"})
@PrepareForTest(android.util.Log.class)
public class DialogTest {
...
```

The side effect is that PowerMock is no longer able to provide it's version of `HttpsURLConnection`

**Next, expose HttpsURLConnection construction, and substitute a mock object**

Introduce a factory for HttpsURLConnection.  E.g.

```
public class HttpsUrlConnectionProvider {
    public HttpsURLConnection getHttpsURLConnection(String dialogUri) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(dialogUri);
        return (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    }
}
```

Create a mock of the HttpsURLConnection object used for HTTP request  E.g.

```
final HttpsURLConnection mockUrlConnection = PowerMockito.mock(HttpsURLConnection.class);
PowerMockito.when(mockUrlConnection, "getResponseCode").thenReturn(200);
PowerMockito.when(mockUrlConnection, "getOutputStream").thenReturn(outputStream);

// Replace the HttpsURLConnection factory with one that returns our mock HttpsURLConnection
HttpsUrlConnectionProvider mockConnFactory = new HttpsUrlConnectionProvider() {
    public HttpsURLConnection getHttpsURLConnection(String dialogUri) throws
            IOException {
       return mockUrlConnection;
    }
};
dialog.setHttpsUrlConnectionProvider(mockConnFactory);
```

Comment: I had a somewhat related problem and `@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*"})` was enough for me :)