# Create unit test using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

Iam trying to create a junit test case for the below functionality setUrl. How can i mock the java url class with mockito

```
   public void setUrl(String url) {      
            this.url = URLUtil.processURL(url);
            try {
                URL dst = new URL(this.url);
                InputStream is = dst.openStream();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is);

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                while(scanner.hasNextLine())
                    sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");


                if (validate(sb.toString())) {
                   --------
                } else {

                }
                is.close();
                scanner.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }        
    }


    private boolean validate(String content) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Boolean isJsonValid = false;
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
          --------
          //json validation goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {          
        }
        return isJsonValid;
    }
```

code tried

```
 URL mockedURL = PowerMockito.mock(URL.class);
        MockedHttpConnection mockedConnection = PowerMockito.mock(MockedHttpConnection.class);

        PowerMockito.whenNew(URL.class).withParameterTypes(String.class).withArguments(sourceUrl).thenReturn(mockedURL);
        PowerMockito.when(mockedURL.openConnection()).thenReturn(mockedConnection);
```

But I'm not sure whether I'm following the right way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are not showing any effort to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: sorry....I added the code part i tried...But Iam not sure

Comment: Looks good to me. Have you... simply tried it?

Comment: To mock URLConnection (HttpConnection), you have to supply to `mock()` method `HttpConnection` class rather than `MockedHttpConnection` class. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334139/how-to-mock-a-url-connection

Comment: I appreciate the accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two answers:

- when *mocking* calls to `new()`, you **simply** have to follow the **all** the mandatory steps, as outlined [here](http://benkiefer.com/blog/2013/04/23/powermockito-constructor-mocking/) for example. Meaning: you need to use the @PrepareForTest annotation, and the correct runner.
- but the real point is: you should't be calling `new()` in the first place. That makes it just harder to test your code. It forces you to rely on PowerMock(ito). And this dependency makes your life a lot harder!

Meaning: it is technically possible and straight forward to mock calls to `new()`, you only need to follow the recipe for that. But the better long term solution is to rework your production code so that you can test it without PowerMock(ito). For example by using some sort of dependency injection that provides some URL object to your code under test.